# c language how to create string with inputs and filename dynamically

Tags: c, input, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have c code like this,

foo.c

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
FILE *fd;
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]);
    char *temp = "_%d_%d_%d", (a,b,c); // I do not know how to create this string
    char *fileName = (char*) malloc(500*sizeof(char));
    sprintf(fileName, "bar%s.txt", temp);
    fd = fopen(fileName, 'w');
    return 0;
}
```

then if I pass the argument after compile, 
./foo 11 13 15
I expect file name as bar_11_13_15.txt since I create string variable with command line argument. 
How can I create string(or char[]) and pass it to file name?

Comment: How about `snprintf(fileName, 500, "bar_%d_%d_%d.txt", a, b, c);`?

Comment: Also, you don't need to allocate `fileName` dynamically, an ordinary array is fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 4)  // make sure there are enough arguments
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int a = atoi(argv[1]); // dont
    int b = atoi(argv[2]); // use
    int c = atoi(argv[3]); // globals!

    char fileName[500];
    snprintf(fileName, sizeof fileName, "bar_%d_%d_%d.txt", a, b, c);
    FILE *fd = fopen(fileName, "w"); // mind the quotation marks
}
```